# C++ newbie: destructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, destructor

I'm just creating a simple list and then destroying it. And something is going wrong and I always get this annoying error message:

```
Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

class list
{
protected:
    node *top;
public:
    list()
    {
        top=NULL;
    }

    list random()
    {
        int x=rand()%10;
        for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
            node *p=new node;
            p->data=rand()%100;
            p->next=top;
            top=p;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void show()
    {
        for(node *p=top; p; p=p->next)
        {
            cout<<p->data<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    ~list()
    {
        node *r;
        for(node *p=top; p; p=r)
        {
            r=p->next;
            delete p;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    srand(GetTickCount());
    list a;
    a.random().show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're violating the [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/636019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are copying your `list` but you don't define a copy constructor. The implicitly defined copy constructor will just copy the `top` pointer so you end up attempting to delete the same chain of nodes twice.

The copy occurs when you `return *this;` from your `random()` member function returning a copy of `*this` by value.

The shortest fix would be to make your class non-copyable by declaring a copy constructor and copy assignment operator in the private section of your class.

```
private:
    list(const list&);
    list& operator=(const list&);
```

You can then make `random` return `void`, there doesn't seem to be a good reason why it makes a copy as well.

You could then just call it like this:

```
    list a;
    a.random();
    a.show();
```

The longer fix would be to make your `list` copyable by making a full implementation of   `list(const list&)` and `list& operator=(const list&)` that correctly duplicates all the nodes of the source `list` being copied.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
list random()
```

should be:

```
list &random()
```

The reason is that your version returns a copy of your instance `a`, and that copy get destructed after `show()` is called.. and that destruction destroys the same memory as that `a` is using. If you really want to have `random()` return a copy, you need to implement a copy constructor that does a deep copy of the internal list that `a` has.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an "annoying error message", it is telling you that your program has somehow corrupted memory.  Quite important actually.

You create a copy of your list when you `return *this`, but you never define a copy constructor, so you end up deleting your top node twice.